# Issue while using contains() for multilist with sitecore Query string?

Tags: sitecore-query

While using query string as data-source getting some issue and facing challanges, here is the Query-string:

```
ancestor::*[@@templatename='A']/Shared/*[@@templatename='AB']/*[contains(@MutlilistFieldName,'wants to pass parentid')]
```

How can we pass `parentid` as string to the contains method? Or how can we declare string variable to the Sitecore Query string?

When I am trying

```
ancestor::*[@@templatename='A']/Shared/*[@@templatename='AB']/*[contains(@MutlilistFieldName,@@parentid)]
```

then it's return all the items instead of checking `parentid` selected from multilist.